# Unix Scripting: date output and Newline(\n) not working

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i have 2 problems

1. whenever i ran the code below, it returns the 2nd date to 20, 30, 40, 50 and so on..
2. the "\n" won't work on my code, and i don't know why, i tried some tests, but for the code on the date , won't go to next **(Answered)**

Heres the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Testing Data entry for the 1st 7 days of the month"
min=01
max=7

while [ $min -lt 8 ]; do

  echo -e "\n `date +"$min"%m%Y` $min \n" >> test.txt

  let min=min+1
done


min=`date +%d -d "-1 month -$(($(date +%-d)-1)) day"`
```

cat test.txt

```
echo -e "Testing\nNewline"
echo -n > test.txt
```

My expected outcome shoud be:
01032014 1
02032014 2
03032014 3
04032014 4
05032014 5
06032014 6
07032014 7

but the outcome is this:
01032014 1
2032014 2
3032014 3
4032014 4
5032014 5
6032014 6
7032014 7

Comment: Can you explain your expected output and what you mean by `1.` a bit more? Also why are you resetting `min` near the end (doesn't look like you're using it anywhere)?

Comment: 1.) My goal is this output:
01032014 1
02032014 2
03032014 3
04032014 4
05032014 5
06032014 6
07032014 7

Comment: You're putting `$min` as part of the arguments to the [tag:date] command, so it's getting interpreted somehow. If you just want to have 01..07 do something like `for min in {01..07}; do echo "$min$(date +%m%Y)"; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just using `cat test.txt`. 
do not echo the result of cat.

Comment: +1 This feels like the answer, `echo $(some command)` should perform word splitting on output of $(some command), so would split proceeding and trailing IFS, `echo "$(some command)"` would probably work, but obviously no reason to as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your `echo -e` line with this to get new lines:

```
{ echo; date "+$min %m%Y $min"; echo; } >> test.txt
```